# Why did David advise Solomon to kill Joab

Tags: david, death

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did David advise Solomon to kill Joab?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/why-did-david-advise-solomon-to-kill-joab)

Joab was a loyal captain in charge for King David 
He won lot of battles for his king. 
He had also risked his life in many occasions for the sake of Kingdom of Israel and David 

Accepted that he did do some mistakes 
1) He killed Abner who came to reconcile with David. Joab might have felt threatened by this reconciliation 
2) He killed Amasa who was made captain by David 
3) He killed Absalom for whom David had given specific instructions not harm him in any ways

But I still don't feel that Joab should have been punished and given death sentence for his mistakes.

Let me know your thoughts.